# Google map v2 Heatmap for specific location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, heatmap, google-maps-api-2

I want to put a heat map for a specific location.

Here in my code, i want to put a heat map on the specific location using an onClick button function.
but then it requires me to have a `java.util.collections<com.google.android.gms.model.latLng>` in the .data

```
 double wa = 14.6228;
 double xa = 121.0581;
   LatLng test= new LatLng(wa,xa);

    HeatmapTileProvider mProvider;
    TileOverlay mOverlay;
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(test).build();
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(mProvider));
```

I'm using this heatmap to represent the quantity/amount of the population in the specific location/area.

Is there any other way to put a heatmap into only a specific location using onClick button function?

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare your list as:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> lists = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

then add your code, it should work.

```
double wa = 14.6228;
double xa = 121.0581;




lists.add(new LatLng(wa,xa));




HeatmapTileProvider mProvider;
TileOverlay mOverlay;
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(lists).build();
mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
        .tileProvider(mProvider));
```